# Render of array elements in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have a problem with my component, I need to render list of skills-elements from array in **export.data**. 
I think, that I missed some arguments in my **map**:

```
const React = require('react')

class Post extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { route } = this.props
    const post = route.page.data
    return this.props.route.page.data.skills.map(() => (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.route.page.data.title}</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>{this.props.route.page.data.skills}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
   )
  }
}
Post.propTypes = {
  route: React.PropTypes.object,
}
export default Post

exports.data = {
  title: 'Tech Skills',
  skills: ['One skill', 'Two skill'],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recieve the `skill` inside your map, since your map function will recieve each element of the array.

You can get the information of each element in the skill object that the map recieves.

Also, with your code, beware that you will be showing the `<h1>` title for each element that you are printing. You should do something like this:

```jsx
return (
   <div>
       <h1>{this.props.route.page.data.title}</h1>
       <ul>
           {
             this.props.route.page.data.skills.map((skill) => {
               return <li key={skill.id}>{skill}</li>
             })
           }
       </ul>
   </div>
)
```

Here, you will only show the title once, and afterwards you will create a element of the list of each skill. Also remember that the `key` parameter is needed if you are creating JSX elements inside a map or any iterating function, since React uses this key to better optimize the re-rendering of the component

Hope it helps!

Comment: Federico, thanks. You are right, I need only list with elements and not need to duplicate my <h1>. 
Only one thing is confused me now. My console shows me:
"skill is not defined",  before my changes everything was ok, and I write `this.props.route.page.data.skills.map((skill)` - so I don't know why "skill is not defined".

Answer (score 1):

The callback in `map` function received the iterated element as its argument. Also, your `render` function should return a single container, which contains the list of elements. So you need to do something like this:

```jsx
return (
<div>
  {this.props.route.page.data.skills.map((skill) => (
    <div key={skill}>
      <h1>{this.props.route.page.data.title}</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>{skill}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>)
```

Note also that you need to give each `<div>` a `key` attribute to avoid errors in react.

Comment: Yes, I understand the general idea, but my trouble is how to do it exactly :)
Now my console shows error to me like: "Post.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object."

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, you need to wrap the whole `map` thing in another container component, so the component `render` function returns a single element instead of an array of elements. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is, you are returning more than **one element from render method** (an array). We can't return multiple elements so wrap them inside a `div`.

Don't forget that the `render()` is basically a `function`, Functions always take in a number of parameters and always return exactly one value.

Like this:

```
render () {
     const { route } = this.props;
     const post = route.page.data;
     return <div>
         {this.props.route.page.data.skills.map(el => (
             <div>
                 ...
             </div>
         ))}
       </div>
    )
}
```

Inside the `map` body `el` will be each `object` of the array, to access any value use `el.keyName`.